# How to automatically update typescript class references to the different location in Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code to work on `Angular` project. As part of refactoring, I'm trying to move some files (interfaces) from app to library. If I drag-drop the file in `VSC` it updates its references only in files that refer to it by relative path. All other references that use

> "@core/models"

to import that interface are ignored.

Example: if I move `user.model.ts` file all files that refer to it as example like `import { User } from '../../models/user';` will be changed to `import { User } from '../../../../../../libs/mylib/src/lib/models/user';` but all references that refer to it like this `import { User} from '@core/models';` not updated.

If I select interface name, right-click and select "Find all references" VSC does show all references correctly in the list. There are about 300 references to that file so I really don't want to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a way for VSCode to do it automagically and more importantly: reliably.

I would do a global find and replace either via the command line or VSCode itself, and then you can rely on the TypeScript compiler to let you know if an import is wrong.

Comment: I dont think global replace is possible. In bunch of places its `import { Passenger, User, Passport } from '@core/models';` mixed inside other names.